# Doble checbox (Uno debajo del otro) con un input

Tags: html, html5, formularios

Pues eso, estoy intentando colocar dos `checkbox` uno debajo del otro, que eso si lo conseguí, pero quiero que por consiguiente, al lado aparezca un `input`que ocupe el tamaño de los dos `checkbox`.

https://jsfiddle.net/6pLxp202/

```
<td>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td colspan="0"><input class="form-control " type="text" name="totalfinal" id="totalfinal"  value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
</tr>
</td>
```

Además debe de ir al lado de `Importe Total` para los que veais el `JSFiddle` y se coloca debajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así ?

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td rowspan="2"><input class="form-control " type="text" name="totalfinal" id="totalfinal"  value="" style="height: 30px;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Hay que añadir rowspan a dos para que la celda ocupe dos filas, después hay que aumentar el tamaño del input para que ocupe lo mismo que los dos check

Comment: Intenta explicar las modificaciones que has realizado a parte de colgar solo el código :)

Comment: Comentario añadido ;)

Answer (score 1):

@Alberto he hecho un ejemplo de maquetación muy sencillo sin tabla, creo que es más o menos lo que buscas. He dejado el código css asociado a los elementos del html para que se vea rápidamente, si usas esta aproximación lo conveniente sería trasladarlo a un archivo css para mantener el código limpio.

Se puede hacer con tablas, aunque es preferible usarlas para tabular datos y no para maquetar.

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; width=50%;">
   <p>Dirección de entrega</p>
   <div style="display:inline-block; width=20%; vertical-align:top;">
     <input type="checkbox" style="margin-top:24px;"/>
     <br>
     <input type="checkbox" style="margin-top:24px;"/>
   </div>
   <div style="display:inline-block; width=20%; border:1px solid #444;">
     <p style="padding: 0 10px;">Elecno Deimos <br>
     Calle Francia 9 <br>
     Pol. Ind. La Nava III <br>
     13500 Puertollano (Ciudad Real)</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; width=45%; vertical-align:top;">
  <p>Importe total</p>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: El ejemplo del OP parece una especie de inventario de artículos, podría ser perfectamente una tabla.

Comment: Si la parte inicial puede ser perfectamente una tabla, la parte final a la que se refiere la pregunta son datos generales y no corresponden necesariamente a una estructura de tabla, a eso me refiero en la respuesta.

Comment: Ok, esa parte no tiene porque ser una tabla, acabo de ver que es una factura.